# How to take screenshot of full page through simple program?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-9, ui-automation, screen-capture, browser-automation

My requirement is to take screenshot of full page in Internet Explorer. I am aware of different tools available online for doing the same but since I want to achieve this on system where I don't have Admin rights, I can do it only with some program which doesn't require any installation.
I am looking for a program which can accept input(site URLs) from excel and then take full page screen shots of those sites.
Till now I only managed to open a site in IE, then do F11 to maximize screen and take screenshot of it. But, that gives cropped page snap since page height is more. I tried this with PowerShell.
Any suggestion/ideas?

```
Capturing a screenshot

Param(
#[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]
$Path = "C:\Sagar\Screens"
)    

$FileName = "$env:COMPUTERNAME - $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss).bmp"
$File = "$Path\$FileName"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Gather Screen resolution information
$Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
$Width = $Screen.Width
$Height = $Screen.Height
$Left = $Screen.Left
$Top = $Screen.Top

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application

$ie.Visible = $true

$ie.Navigate2("https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-    instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20send%20keys%20through%20powershell")

while($ie.busy){
Sleep -Seconds 2
}

Sleep -Seconds 2
$sig = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool      ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32

# Minimize window
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($ie.HWND, 2)
# Restore window
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($ie.HWND, 3)

#$ie.FullScreen = $true
Sleep -seconds 3

[void]     [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F11}")

sleep -Seconds 2

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Create bitmap using the top-left and bottom-right bounds
$bitmap = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Bitmap -ArgumentList    $ie.Width, $ie.Height

# Create Graphics object
$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bitmap)
$ie.Left
$ie.Top
# Capture screen
$graphic.CopyFromScreen($ie.Left, $ie.Top, 0, 0, $bitmap.Size)

# Save to file
$bitmap.Save($File) 

Write-Output "Screenshot saved to:"
Write-Output $File
```

#

Found a solution to this. There is this thing called 'Watin' which helps in automation using IE and Firefox. It has a method to capture full page screenshot. Though screenshot quality is average, Watin works perfectly.

```
    $executingScriptDirectory = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

    $filePath = $executingScriptDirectory + "\WatiN-2.1.0.1196\bin\net40\WatiN.Core.dll" #$executingScriptDirectory + "\net20\WatiN.Core.dll"
    $filePath1 = $executingScriptDirectory + "\WatiN-2.1.0.1196\bin\net40\Interop.SHDocVw.dll"

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($filePath);
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($filePath1);

    $url = "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20send%20keys%20through%20powershell"

     $ie = new-object WatiN.Core.IE $URL

     while($ie.busy){
                    sleep -milliseconds 50
                }

     $ie.BringToFront()

     $ie.CaptureWebPageToFile("C:\Sagar\Scripts\IsIt.jpg");
```

Comment: I am not sure which part needs more information. Are you asking for us to fix your PowerShell script that you are not showing us (Show us the code first please)? Are you asking for a program that will do what your are asking (off-topic)? Do you really need a screen capture? Is there not just some parts you can scrape off the webpage instead?

Comment: Sorry Matt, m new to StackOverflow , m still learning on how to use it. Have added the code of what I did till now :)
I am trying to achieve full page screen capture through Powershell. But after lots of R&D, I think it might be difficult to do it with PS. So, if you can help me with Powershell or some other program, anything will do for me. I just want the Full Page Screen Capture.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for adding the code as now this question can be looked at easier now since we have something to work off of. What is the motivation for the screen capture though? You might be able to print the page to file? Depends on the page as this can distort it. What if the webpage needs to scroll?

Comment: This code gives me screenshot of what's visible on the page. But the invisible area under the page for which we have scroll is not captured. That's what I am aiming for. Visible + Invisible area of the page and create Image of it.

Comment: Found a solution to this. There is this thing called 'Watin' which helps in automation using IE and Firefox. It has a method to capture full page screenshot. Though screenshot quality is average, Watin works perfectly. Please let me know if you can make the image quality better.